# Incompatible pointer types with nested pointers

Tags: c

I have a function whose parameter is of type `char *(*)[]`, and I call the function on an object of type `char ***`. Why does GCC warn of "incompatible pointer type"?

**Edit**: OK, I just realised `[]` should not be used for anything other than the first index. But I don't really understand what `char *(*)[]` actually means for a function parameter.

Comment: `(*)[]` is a pointer to an array, which is different than an array of pointers.

Comment: Completely agree, here you have a *pointer-to-pointer-to-array* `char *(*)[]` and a *pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer-to-type* `char ***`. (note: being a *three-star programmer* usually isn't a compliment).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin but I thought that it should be compatible..?

Comment: Comment (to revised question) `char *(*)[ ]` should cause problems as it is a pointer to an *incomplete type*. `char (*)[const]` is a *pointer-to-array of const number of chars*. (e.g. adding another level of indirection is like a *pointer to 2D array*) Omitting the `const` leaves it as an *incomplete type*. The `char ***` is complete, but the compiler has trouble with the fact they are not the same type.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `char *(*)[]` is a pointer to an array of pointers to `char`, not a pointer-to-pointer-to-array.

Comment: Hmm. How did I botch the verbiage... `(*)[]` (pointer to array), `*[]` (array of pointers), Why isn't `*(*)[]` a (pointer-to-pointer-to-array)?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `(*)[]` is a pointer to an array. If you put another `*` on the front of it, it becomes a pointer to an array of pointers. Also I do not believe `char (*)[const]` is legal. You can use `const` like that in the outermost array-type part of a function parameter declaration, it which csae it declares a `const` pointer (the “array” type is adjusted to be a pointer type). E.g., `char foo[const]` declares parameter `foo` to a `const` pointer to `char`.

Comment: My bad, I meant `const` as a fixed number, not the type qualifier. Poor choice of `const`. Yes, I see the pointer to array of pointers, essentially a pointer to multiple pointers to array, or pointer to an array of pointers. That's what I was saying -- incorrectly (verbiage corrected)

Comment: @user3386109, in a parameter declaration, `(*)[]` is equivalent to `*(*)`, i'm afraid.  An array requires explicit dimension to be a complete type definition, or an initializer, so the compiler can guess the array size from the initializer.

Comment: @LuisColorado The question should have shown the actual function prototype. Since it did not, it's just a guess as to what that function prototype looks like. Clearly, any **valid** function prototype would include a numeric constant inside the brackets.

Comment: @user3386109, the question says _I have a function **whose parameter is of type**..._  Most probably, the parameter is declared as shown in the question.

Comment: being a 3 star programmer is not a compliment.  You probably should restructure your code to eliminate that 3 start declarations.  [3star](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

They are not compatible.

```
char *(*p)[]
```

this means `p` is a pointer to an array - and that array contains `char*`.

```
char* p[2][3];
```

when passed to a function will decay into that type of object.(This is an example showing a case where an array decaying into this). But when passing an array you need to pass any other dimension size information apart from the first (decaying occurs). Without specifying this when you use the passed object and index into it - it would not be possible to correctly retrieve the elements.

So it would be right to see this

```
char *(*p)[3]
```

in the function signature.

And again `char***` is not in anyway same as the one described above. `char***` - it would be pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a char.

Comment: @user1537366.: What is incompatible? They are not incompatible....I said it...it is basically decayed pointer to the first element of the `char*` array.  The thing is I explained why they shouldn't be the same. Because you are considering different variables. Just let me know - I will try to clarify as much as possible.